# PIP is gone and can't install it back

Tags: python, pip

I had everything working fine, then out of nowhere I keep getting this

```
PS C:\Users\rygra\Documents\Ryan Projects\totalwine-product-details-scraper> ensurepip
ensurepip : The term 'ensurepip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.   
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ensurepip
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ensurepip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
PS C:\Users\rygra\Documents\Ryan Projects\totalwine-product-details-scraper> py get-pip.py
C:\Users\rygra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\rygra\\Documents\\Ryan Projects\\totalwine-product-details-scraper\\get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\rygra\Documents\Ryan Projects\totalwine-product-details-scraper>
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel >  Programs > Programs and features > search python and right click and click the change button > choose to modify > Make sure to tick this one:
[image: Python installation window screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're on Windows.

As described in https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#ensurepip, you should run:

```
py -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a virtual environment with
`python3 -m venv venv`  or `python -m venv venv` in case the first doesn't work.

Then, open the folder "Scripts" inside of the created venv's folder and copy the files with "pip" in their name.

Finally, paste those files on the "Scripts" folder of your original python folder (the one you had installed on your computer before).